# Integral and limit

Tags: integration, limits

I want to calculate the limit is given by
$$\underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,{{\int_{0}^{n}{\left( 1-\frac{x}{n} \right)}}^{n}}{{e}^{-2x}}dx$$
Can i apply the strategy as follow? why?
$$ \underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,{{\int_{0}^{n}{\left( 1-\frac{x}{n} \right)}}^{n}}{{e}^{-2x}}dx={{\int_{0}^{+\infty }{\underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,\left( 1-\frac{x}{n} \right)}}^{n}}{{e}^{-2x}}dx$$ 
Thank u for your guideness.

Comment: Either dominated convergence theorem (DCT) or monotone convergence (MCT) theorem will justify your manipulation, though conditions for MCT is a bit harder to check for this one.

Comment: @SangchulLee : If one had $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$ rather than $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}$ then I'd be looking at whether the conditions needed for DCT or MCT are satisfied.  But this is different. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, I thought that the limit was a typo of $\lim_{n\to\infty}$, because $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ just made no sense to me here. But, yes, if $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ is what user math truly intended, then my comment is simply wrong.

Comment: ok, I confess to a suspicion that $n\to\infty$ rather than $x\to\infty$ was intended. $\qquad$

Comment: yes you are right i should write $n\to\infty$

Comment: This exercise is almost the same as: *prove the limit product formula for the $\Gamma$ function, given its integral representation*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases one has
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_A f_n(x)\,dx \ne \int\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)\,dx
$$
even when both limits exist.  For example,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{(0,1)} n\cdot 1_{(0,\,1/n)}(x) \, dx = 1 \ne 0 = \int_{(0,1)} \lim_{n\to\infty} n\cdot 1_{(0,\,1/n)}(x) \, dx.
$$
However, the two expressions are equal if $0 \le f_1\le f_2 \le f_3\le \cdots$, and they are equal if
$$
\int_A \sup_n \left| f_n(x) \right| \, dx <\infty.
$$
The first of those two propositions is Lebesgue's monotone convergence theorem; the second is Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem.  The former is applicable in this case, if you can show that $0\le f_1 \le f_2 \le f_3 \le \cdots$.

Answer (score 2):

This exercise is almost the same as: *prove the limit product formula for the $\Gamma$ function, given its integral representation*. The sequence of functions defined on $\mathbb{R}^+$ by:
$$ f_n(x) = \left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\cdot \mathbb{1}_{(0,n)}(x) $$
is pointwise monotonically convergent to $e^{-x}$, and $f_n(x),e^{-x},f_n(x)e^{-x}$ are non-negative integrable functions over $\mathbb{R}^+$. By monotonicity, it follows that the wanted limit is just
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-3x}\,dx = \color{red}{\frac{1}{3}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

We can write the integral as

$$\int_0^\infty (1-x/n)^n e^{-2x}\chi_{[0,n]}(x)\,dx.$$

Clearly these integrands are bounded above by $e^{-2x} \in L^1[0,\infty).$ And the integrands converge pointwise to $e^{-3x}$ on $[0,\infty).$ We're done by the dominated convergence theorem: The answer is $\int_0^\infty e^{-3x}\, dx = 1/3.$